# Looking for a creepy worm in a movie scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

There is one particular scene in an ~80s Horror-Scifi movie I remember which has been very fascinating as a child. Now I'm looking for the movie title.

There is a flesh-colored, slimy worm crouching on and beneath the metal grid floor of some kind of space ship or boat. It is undiscovered by the crew at that time and the climax is already increasing in that scene. I think the worm is developing further in the movie.

I know there are many movies with latex monsters and worms similar to that. I recently watched "Galaxy of Terror" and "Leviathan" but couldn't find that particular scene.

Please help!

EDIT:
The worm had a length of maybe 15 cm and started crawling towards the crew.
And I've been pretty sure, it was a space ship until I saw Leviathan which is placed several miles beneath the ocean surface.

Comment: _...some kind of space ship or boat..._ I think if you could narrow it down to either a space ship OR a boat, that would help.

Comment: Your description sounds somewhat like a cybermat or a cybermite from Doctor Who. Are you sure it's a movie?

Comment: @Mr Lister - Aren't cybermats and cybermites always metal-plated and shiny, rather than flesh-colored and slimy?

Comment: A bit later and not a film but could be an X-Files episode ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(The_X-Files)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the space herpe from Ice Pirates?  An egg hatches on the ship and the creature that comes out is moving about the ship throughout the movie.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-me2inj1nNw) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnJrenTkGGE) for examples of the creature, but I believe it gets bigger by the end of the movie.

Comment: Incredible how many films there are of such kind. The space herpe is close, but I can't remember a face on it.